# check if a class added or removed from an html element using element.classList

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a code which will change color of unordered lists of item on mouseover or mouseout.

***(change color to light green when mouse over and light gray on mouseout)***

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gQC2B/4/)

here i have used element.classList mehtod to add or remove id from each list item depending on mouse events.

here i add or remove class randomly.but i want to remove or add by checking whether a previously added class exists or not.**is there any way in javascript to check if an added class exists or not??**

```
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
            li {
                background:lightgray;
                list-style-type:none;
                font-family:Ariel;
                color:white;
                height:30px;
                width:150px;
                font-size:20px;
                font-weight:bold;
                padding:5px;
                margin:2px;
            }
            li.element {
                background:lightgreen;
            }
            li.back {
                background:lightgray;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="uls">
            <li>apple</li>
            <li>orange</li>
            <li>pineapple</li>
            <li>mange</li>
        </ul>
        <script>
            function makeit() {
                var elem = document.getElementById('uls');

                elem.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
                    var target = e.target;
                    if (target.tagName == "LI") {
                        target.classList.remove('back');
                        target.classList.toggle('element');
                    }
                }, false);

                elem.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
                    var target = e.target;
                    if (target.tagName == "LI") {
                        target.classList.remove('element');
                        target.classList.toggle('back');
                    }
                }, false);
            }

            window.onload = makeit;
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think target.tagName == "LI" should be target.tagName == "li".

Comment: What do you mean by "is there any way in javascript to check if an added class exists or not". Do you mean whether there is an associated CSS rule? Whether any element in the document has that class? Whether a particular element has that class?

Comment: using classList.toggle() i added and removed two classes for each of the event handler.what i tried to say is i want to check before removing class during each mouse event if the class exists or not!!i mean if exists then remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see if an element has a particular class, you can use a function like:

```
function hasClass(element, className) {
  var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + className + '(\\s|$)');
  return re.test(element.className);
}
```

or

```
function hasClass(element, className) {
  return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0;
}
```

Comment: why i need (^|\\s) before className .i mean what does \\s supposed to mean in the regex object?

Comment: (^added)i mean double back-slash??

Comment: In the *RegExp* constructor, "\" characters must be quoted, so `new RegExp('\\s')` is equivalent to `/\s/`, and `\s` matches whitespace like space, newline, carriage return, tab, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex match for `element.className` or you can use jQuery's own implementation : **hasClass**

From jQuery source (2.0.3)

```
function (selector) {
    var className = " " + selector + " ",
        i = 0,
        l = this.length;
    for (; i < l; i++) {
        if (this[i].nodeType === 1 && (" " + this[i].className + " ").replace(/[\n\t\r]/g, " ").indexOf(className) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

For more reading, you can head over to [jQuery source viewer of](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.5.0&fn=jQuery.fn.hasClass) or peep into its [source at github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery).